# asterisk with WebRTC in order to implement phone call

Tags: javascript, node.js, asterisk, webrtc

I have to implement webRTC solution which allows phone calls via browser based on asterisk and node.js (video and audio calls are ok thanks to opensource project).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

check this project
https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc

But i have inform you that webrtc is in early beta stage, it is experemental technology.

So to do something in this field you have be sip and node.js guru and understand how to search info in web and deal with sockets.

Comment: just i need to have a combination bettewen webrtc and astersik in order to allow user make phone call via browser . in web the document is not also clear

Comment: You can't use node.js and asterisk at same time. It is different servers. I am sorry, there are no documentation and it is now guru-class task. No way describe it in simple article.

Comment: so ignore node.js at this time we talk about asterisk in webrTC (Html5 and javascript)                                                   something like this  maybe will be helpful ? http://sipml5.org/

Comment: In order to make a PSTN call via WEBRTC ? Are there any opensources

Comment: Sure.Asterisk can do webrtc and can call PSTN. But it still guru-class task.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a prof of concept some time ago and was really easy, well, I had to hack some part of asterisk because of SDP.

Start deploying a Asterisk Server and then use for instance http://sipml5.org/ to connect to or asterisk server, deploying it using node.js. (That was I have done).

Comment: thanks sir do you think that this guide is helpful i was tried it but no success http://ensiwiki.ensimag.fr/index.php/WebRTC_and_the_question_of_interoperability_with_SIP

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays Asterisk support WebRTC quite out of the box.
I followed this is the guides:
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+WebRTC+Support
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/WebRTC+tutorial+using+SIPML5
to configure the server.
On the client side there's just a light web page with jssip
That's the working demo I realized: clic2call.demo.sociale.it